# Is is possible for a single WF service to be built from multiple .xamlx files?

Tags: workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

It appears that my WF Service can have only one `xamlx` file from which to generate the service interface. How can I change that so that I can support isolated, multiple workflows in the same service?

The idea here is to reduce the complexity of multiple deployments while also reducing the complexity of single `xamlx` workflow definitions.

This should be a real simple answer but I could not find the answer.  VS will let you add two `xamlx` to the project so it would seem that there would be a solution.....

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could consider Workflow versioning and WorkflowIdentity to enable hosting multiple versions of a workflow side-by-side. More info here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh305677(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I am not trying to host multiple versions of a workflow but rather multiple workflows.   I have seen since my post that VS2013 does allow one to add .xaml files (not .xamlx) which are configured with a URL suffix.   The effect of adding these .xaml files is the creation of new namespaces when creating service references--one namespace per xaml(x) file.